Reducer getting error is not assignable type 'readonly any[] | Type<any>'
StoreModule.forRoot({
    counter: counterReducer
})

In above code when I am importing reducer it is giving me error like assignable type 'readonly any[] | Type'.
I can not importing counterReducer successfully.
I have checked solutions from chat GPT and and google but, I cannot get any solution.
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { increase, decrease, reset } from './counter.action';

export const initialState = 0;

const _counterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increase, state => state + 1),
  on(decrease, state => state - 1),
  on(reset, state => initialState)
);

export function counterReducer(state: number | undefined, action: Action) {
  return _counterReducer(state, action);
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Okay please check code now

Please verify if your reducer looks something like this:


import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { increment, decrement, reset } from './counter.actions';

export const initialState = 0;

const _counterReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(increment, state => state + 1),
  on(decrement, state => state - 1),
  on(reset, state => initialState)
);

export function counterReducer(state: number | undefined, action: Action) {
  return _counterReducer(state, action);
}



then in module,


import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { counterReducer } from './counter.reducer'; // Adjust the path as necessary

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // Your components here
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ counter: counterReducer })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [/* Your root component here */]
})
export class AppModule { }



Please try and give feedback if it works!

No, This code is not working. still I am getting error when I am importing StoreModule.

Well can you provide the code for your reducer, so that I can further investigate it?

I have updated my code. Please check it.

Okay, I am checking. Meanwhile, can you please provide the full error log as well?

I found the solution actually, I am using standalone component structure. so, after importing StoreModule inside main.ts file It is working properly.

Glad to hear that!
